# multiple HTML5 canvas with Neurosky sensor input is not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mindwave

I have created multiple html5 canvas using instantiation mode in P5JS. I am using Neurosky mindwave EEG sensor to activate and deactivate canvas one by one. Neurosky mindwave EEG sensor can detect user's eye blink which I am using as input. When user blinks, it should activate one canvas and deactivate another canvas and vice-versa.I am using Neurosky mindwave EEG sensor to activate and deactivate canvas one by one. Neurosky mindwave EEG sensor can detect user's eye blink which I am using as input. When user blinks, it should activate one canvas and deactivate another canvas and vice-versa.

Just to check if my code logic works, I used mouse pressed input to switch between the canvas and it worked perfectly. But, when I used it with the sensor it didn't work.

**What I did** - I have created multiple HTML5 canvas using instantiation mode in P5JS. I have used node-neurosky node module to capture the eyeblink data from the sensor. [Node Module](https://github.com/dluxemburg/node-neurosky)

**What worked** - When I launch the app it takes the eye blink as input for the first time and activate the another canvas but when I blink again it doesn't deactivate the current canvas and activate another canvas. I have tried printing flags to check the code and it is doing fine. Eyeblink gets detected every time when I blink but it doesn't switch the canvas.

**What didn't work** - When I tried to use eye blink strength directly into the sketch.js it didn't work then I created another boolean variable **eyeclick** which also didn't work.

**sketch.js**

```
var stateTwo, stateOne = true;
// sketch one -----------------------------------

var first = new p5(firstSketch, "canvasOne");

function firstSketch(p) {

    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(400, 250);
    }
    p.draw = function() {
        p.background(255, 10, 100);
        p.fill(255);
        p.ellipse(p.width / 2, p.height / 2, 50, 50);
        if (eyeclicked) {
            stateOne = false;
            stateTwo = true;
            console.log(" canvas <-- one");
            // k = 0;
            eyeclicked = false;
        }
        if (stateOne) {
            $('#canvasOne').css('opacity', '1');
            $('#canvasTwo').css('opacity', '0.5');
            // console.log("canvas One");
            p.fill(255, 0, 0);
            p.ellipse(p.random(p.width), p.random(p.height), 50, 50);
        }
    }
}

// sketch two -----------------------------------

var second = new p5(secondSketch, "canvasTwo");

function secondSketch(p) {

    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(400, 250);
    }
    p.draw = function() {
        p.background(60, 250, 100);
        p.fill(0);
        p.ellipse(p.width / 2, p.height / 2, 50, 50);

        if (eyeclicked) {
            stateOne = true;
            stateTwo = false;
            console.log(" canvas <-- two");
            //  k = 0;
            eyeclicked = false;
        }

        if (stateTwo) {
            $('#canvasOne').css('opacity', '0.5');
            $('#canvasTwo').css('opacity', '1');
            // console.log("canvas Two");
            p.fill(0, 0, 255);
            p.ellipse(p.random(p.width), p.random(p.height), 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

**NodeCode to connect with sensor connect.js**

```
 var attention = 0;
 var meditation = 0;
 var blink;
 var poorSignalLevel = 0;
 var eyeclicked = false;

 if ("WebSocket" in window) {
     console.log("WebSocket is supported by your Browser. Proceed.");
     // $('#connect-controls').show();
 }

 var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");
 ws.onopen = function() {
     console.log('opened connection');
     ws.send("Hello from websocket client!");
 };

 // whenever websocket server transmit a message, do this stuff
 ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
     // parse the data (sent as string) into a standard JSON object (much easier to use)
     var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
     // handle "eSense" data
     if (data.eSense) {
         $('#brain').css({
             opacity: 1
         });
         attention = data.eSense.attention;
         meditation = data.eSense.meditation;
         // brainProgress('#focusProgress', attention);
         // brainProgress('#medProgress', meditation);
         $("#focus").text(attention);
         $("#meditation").text(meditation);
     }

     // handle "blinkStrength" data
     if (data.blinkStrength) {
         blink = data.blinkStrength;
         var blinkcol = "white";
         var eyeVal = map_range(blink, 0, 255, 0, 100);
         $('#eyeBlinkStrength').text(parseInt(eyeVal));
         if (blink > 40) {
             //blinkcol = "rgba(102,211,43,1.0)";
             eyeclicked = true;
             //  k++;   
             console.log(blink + " " + eyeclicked);
         } else blinkcol = "white";
         $('#eyeBlink').css({
             width: eyeVal,
             height: eyeVal,
             background: blinkcol
         });
     } else {
         blink = 0;
         eyeclicked = false;
     }

     // handle "poorSignal" data
     if (data.poorSignalLevel != null) {
         poorSignalLevel = parseInt(data.poorSignalLevel);
     }
 };

 // when websocket closes connection, do this stuff
 ws.onclose = function() {
     // websocket is closed.
     console.log("Connection is closed...");
 };


 function map_range(value, low1, high1, low2, high2) {
     return low2 + (high2 - low2) * (value - low1) / (high1 - low1);
 }
```

**EDIT** [**CODE PEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/xblack/pen/NpEvwm)

**Mouse Input Based** Code which demonstrate the logic of switching between multiple canvas. It works perfectly. Try to click into the center circle

```
var stateTwo, stateOne = true;
var eyeIsBlinked;
// sketch one -----------------------------------

var first = new p5(firstSketch, "canvasOne");

function firstSketch(p) {

    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(400, 250);
    }
    p.draw = function() {
        p.background(255, 10, 100);
        p.fill(255);
        p.ellipse(p.width / 2, p.height / 2, 50, 50);
        if (p.mouseIsPressed && p.dist(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, p.width / 2, p.height / 2) < 50) {
            stateOne = false;
            stateTwo = true;
            console.log(" <-- one");
            // k = 0;
            // window.eyeIsBlinked = false;
            // blink = 0;
        }
        if (stateOne) {
            $('#canvasOne').css('opacity', '1');
            $('#canvasTwo').css('opacity', '0.5');
            // console.log("canvas One");
            p.fill(255, 0, 0);
            p.ellipse(p.random(p.width), p.random(p.height), 50, 50);
        }
    }
}

// sketch two -----------------------------------

var second = new p5(secondSketch, "canvasTwo");

function secondSketch(p) {

    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(400, 250);
    }
    p.draw = function() {
        p.background(60, 250, 100);
        p.fill(0);
        p.ellipse(p.width / 2, p.height / 2, 50, 50);

        if (p.mouseIsPressed && p.dist(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, p.width / 2, p.height / 2) < 50) {
            stateOne = true;
            stateTwo = false;
            console.log(" <-- two");
            //  k = 0;
            //  window.eyeIsBlinked = false;
            //blink = 0;
        }

        if (stateTwo) {
            $('#canvasOne').css('opacity', '0.5');
            $('#canvasTwo').css('opacity', '1');
            // console.log("canvas Two");
            p.fill(0, 0, 255);
            p.ellipse(p.random(p.width), p.random(p.height), 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your project works. But I guess the problem might be a scope problem. Both files are using the `eyeclicked` variable, but they might be using two different variables. Try to make sure that they're using the same variable by using it inside the `window` global variable.

So instead of `eyeclicked` use `window.eyeclicked`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it didn't do anything. I added window.eyeclicked but it didn't do anything :( Here is the screenshot of the code - https://ibb.co/jgKugF. It shows the two cavas created usinng P5JS and if you notice one is faded and other is not. The faded one is non-active canvas and other is active canvas. Both canvas shows randomly moving ellipse when active and non-active cnavas show no activity. It should switch whenever user blink his eyes.

Comment: Are you sure that the `ws.onmessage` event handler is being called? Try debugging see if it's going all through the code. put a `debugger;` in the first line of the function, open your browser's webdevtool and reload the page.

Comment: Yes, it does get called. I check it. Also, eyeClicked get pass into the code  when I comment out one of the canvas code completely. It works for both canvas code when one is inactive but i doesn't work when both code are active.

Comment: It's hard to help on this, It's a logic problem I guess, nothing related to the technologies used on it. Try to make and opacity change after you define the eyeclicked=true instead of in both draw functions of the canvas. basically move the `if (eyeclicked) {`, `if (stateOne) {` and `if (stateTwo) {` to after the `eyeclicked = true;` in the **NodeCode to connect with sensor connect.js**

Comment: Because it's calling first the first canvas draw function, so the state will be always `stateOne = false; stateTwo = true;` then it sets `eyeclicked=false` so it will never go through the second canvas draw state change.

Comment: Mosmann I wish I can agree with you but the logic is correct in my understanding [please excuse my tone]. It works perfectly when I use mouseIsPressed instead of eyeClicked so I believe it has something to do with the multiple canvas where only one canvas can take sensor input actively for your further clarification I would add the mousePressed version of code. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Hehe, no worries, but still. It's a logic problem. See, in your codepen, you check for `p.mouseIsPressed`. But this variable is contextual, each canvas have one, and it will be true if the mouse is clicked inside that same canvas. In the other hand, with the `eyeclicked`, it's a global variable, that both canvas use, but the thing is, the first canvas draw function is always called before the second canvas draw function, and the draw function set `eyeclicked` as false, resulting in that the `eyeclicked` variable will never be true inside the second canvas draw function.

Comment: @ João Mosmann Thank you so much :) :) I fixed the problem and yes it was a logical error :) thank you again